# Slicing a NURBS surface

Tags: 3d, slice, geometry-surface, nurbs, geometry-slice

I have a [NURBS surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NURBS) which has 4 curved edges. *(I have the 4 bezier points for the curves)*

I'd like to slice the NURBS surface with a slicing-plane thats on-axis *(not as advanced as 3DSMAX!)*, and calculate a curve where the slicing-plane and NURBS surface intersects.

Comment: Are we talking 3D or just numbers? Could you maybe attach a picture for reference? I think I'm getting at what you mean but you've constrained yourself to just the X, Y or Z axis? The general case would be intersection between surface and plane? This sounds awfully a lot like projecting on a plane.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574732/calculate-the-horizon-of-a-curved-face-not-extrema

Answer (score 1):

Well.. The R in 'NURBS' is for rational. It's a division of two polynoms. Your (axis-aligned) plane gives you a very simple fun set of points, (x,y,z) such that z is the given z. Solve. Not very helpful perhaps. Is [this](http://www.risc.uni-linz.ac.at/projects/basic/cgal/workdone/nurbs-97-30.ps.gz) more like what you had in mind?